# Can I shorten this SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have write a query to get the total number assignments which had no activity from last 5 months including those assignments which were created five months ago and never had any visit on it.

Can i shorten this query any further so i don't have to use the outer query.

```
  SELECT @NumNoActivity = COUNT(QnoActivity.AssignmentID) FROM

  (

    SELECT a.AssignmentID
    FROM Assignments a
    LEFT JOIN VISITS v ON v.AssignmentID = a.AssignmentID
    WHERE a.CurrentStatus = 1  
    AND a.StaffID = @StaffID
    GROUP BY a.AssignmentID,  a.CreatedDate
    HAVING DATEDIFF(MONTH, ISNULL(MAX(v.VisitDate),a.CreatedDate ), GETDATE())  > =5

  ) QnoActivity
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `NOT EXISTS` to remove the join:

```
SELECT @NumNoActivity = COUNT(a.AssignmentID)
FROM Assignments a
WHERE a.CurrentStatus = 1  
AND a.StaffID = @StaffID
AND NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT * FROM VISITS v 
         WHERE v.AssignmentID = a.AssignmentID
         AND v.VisitDate>DATEADD(month,-5,GETDATE()))
```

**UPDATE**

Based on Gordon Linoff's comment, the query was missing the `Assignments.CreatedDate` condition. Here's an updated version:

```
SELECT @NumNoActivity = COUNT(a.AssignmentID)
FROM Assignments a
WHERE a.CurrentStatus = 1  
AND a.StaffID = @StaffID
AND (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(VisitDate), a.CreatedDate) FROM VISITS v 
         WHERE v.AssignmentID = a.AssignmentID) <= DATEADD(month,-5,GETDATE())
```

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d143/1) to show how it works. Assignment results are:

- 1 - not included as there's a recent visit
- 2 - included as there's no visit and create date is old
- 3 - included as there's only a recent visit
- 4 - not included as there's no visit but create date is recent
- 5 - not included as there's a recent visit

Comment: you have changed the sql query to use `3 Select Statements`, instead of `2 Select Statements`, do you think its a good habit

Comment: Number of selects in itself doesn't really matter much. What counts is how it will get resolved into an execution plan. Also, a join is effectively 2 selects as well.

Comment: No, i dnt think so, you can see the good explanation here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19835485/two-selects-or-one-select-one-join-in-sql as you can see the execution plan, `Join` is taking less time to execute in the first case

Comment: @Szymon +1 But I think you can use COUNT in the inner query there is no need to use outer query and I would use `v.VisitDate>DATEADD(month,-5,GETDATE())` instead of DATEDIFF so SQL server would be able to use index on `v.VisitDate` to make it faster.

Comment: @HarshSharma That really depends. In this case, a lot on the distribution of data. Also, be mindful that this is not inner join but left join.

Comment: @valex You're very right in both cases. Thank you, I updated my answer.

Comment: @HarshSharma For this query logic if you use JOIN you should use also `GROUP BY` or `COUNT(DISTINCT AssignmentID)`. So `NOT EXISTS` here is instead of `JOIN + GROUP BY`. I don't think it will be slower but real speed sure depends on indexes and data distribution.

Comment: I used the Left join bcz there might be a assignment which never had any visit on it. So if assignment was created 5 months ago and had no visit then it should be included in the list.

Comment: @user1263981 Yes, that makes sense for your logic. In this case `NOT EXISTS` will be true and it will work the same way.

Comment: It would be better if you use `(SELECT 1 FROM VISITS)` in inner query instead of `(SELECT * FROM VISITS)`. It would reduce the number of rows selection time for inner query which is not required in this scenario.

Comment: This doesn't include the condition on the created date, if there are no visits.

Comment: It is not counting those assignments which had no visit.

Comment: @user1263981 . . . I think it is better to put it in the `where` clause of the outer query.

Comment: @user1263981 What is `CreatedDate` on those assignments that had no visits?

Comment: Assignment is kind of a parent table with one to many relation with Visit table. So there can be more than one visit or no visit on an assignment. We are basically checking that how many assignments are there with no visits in past 5 months.

Comment: I updated the answer with SQL Fiddle demonstrating how it works.

Comment: Pls add last visit date '20130911' into your schema with assignment 6 and you will see it won't show the assignment 6 even though DATEDIFF(MONTH,'11/09/2013',GETDATE()) = 5

Comment: I think it is that DATEADD(month,-5,GETDATE()) function which gives '03/09/2013' , DateDiff is slightly different DATEDIFF(MONTH,'11/09/2013',GETDATE()) = 5

Comment: I have just run the execution plan on both mine and your query and i can't see any difference. The execution plan is just same. Looks like dateadd function is not making any difference.

Comment: I think i better use the 'Day' in DateDiff function instead of 'Month'. Please correct me if i am wrong, DATEDIFF( DAY  ,ISNULL(MAX(v.VisitDate),a.CreatedDate), GETDATE()) >= 153 is same as ATEADD(month,-5,GETDATE()) . If i use the 'DAY' then @Szymon query is correct (it doesn't make any difference in performance)

Comment: `DATEDIFF` doesn't take any rounding into account, just the difference in month/day number. So yes, using 153 days will give you better precision (though it's not completely correct as months are different length but it's better anyway).

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative way to write this query.  You can look at it as the difference etween the total number of "assignments" and the total number of "assignments" that have had activity in the past 4/5 months.

The following takes this approach.  It excludes new "assignments" in the `where` clause and the counts the different in the `select` clause:

```
SELECT (count(distinct a.AssignmentID) -
        count(distinct case when datediff(MONTH, v.VisitDate, GETDATE()) < 5 or
                                 v.VisitDate is null
                            then a.AssignmentId end)
       )
FROM Assignments a LEFT JOIN
     VISITS v
     ON v.AssignmentID = a.AssignmentID
WHERE a.CurrentStatus = 1 AND
      a.StaffID = @StaffID and
      a.CreatedDate <= DATEADD(month, -5, GETDATE());
```

Comment: there is a difference of 6. Should return 38 instead of 32. I think it is missing those assignments which had no visit.

Comment: @user1263981 . . . How embarrassing, because I was specifically thinking about that condition with the `where` clause.  I added the appropriate logic for it.